# equivalent expressions

Tags: math, bitwise-operators, modulo

I'm trying to figure out an equivalent expressions of the following equations using bitwise, addition, and/or subtraction operators. I know there's suppose to be an answer (which furthermore generalizes to work for any modulus 2^a-1, where a is a power of 2), but for some reason I can't seem to figure out what the relation is.

Initial expressions:

```
x = n % (2^32-1);
c = (int)n / (2^32-1); // ints are 32-bit, but x, c, and n may have a greater number of bits
```

My procedure for the first expression was to take the modulo of 2^32, then try to make up the difference between the two modulo's. I'm having trouble on this second part.

```
x = n & 0xFFFFFFFF + difference // how do I calculate difference?
```

I know that the difference `n%(2^32)-n%(2^32-1)` is periodic (with a period of `2^32*(2^32-1)`), and there's a "spike up' starting at multiples of `2^32-1` and ending at `2^32`. After each `2^32` multiple, the difference plot decreases by 1 (hopefully my descriptions make sense)

Similarly, the second expression could be calculated in a similar fashion:

```
c = n >> 32 + makeup // how do I calculate makeup?
```

I think makeup steadily increases by 1 at multiples of `2^32-1` (and decreases by 1 at multiples of `2^32`), though I'm having troubles expressing this idea in terms of the available operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured out the answer to my question:

Compute c first, then use the results to compute x. Assumes that the comparison returns 1 for true, 0 for false. Also, the shifts are all logical shifts.

```
c = (n>>32) + ((t & 0xFFFFFFFF) >= (0xFFFFFFFF - (n>>32)))

x = (0xFFFFFFFE - (n & 0xFFFFFFFF) - ((c - (n>>32))<<32)-c) & 0xFFFFFFFF
```

edit: changed x (only need to keep lower 32 bits, rest is "junk")

Answer (score 0):

You can use these identities:

```
n mod (x - 1) = (((n div x) mod (x - 1)) + ((n mod x) mod (x - 1))) mod (x - 1)
n div (x - 1) = (n div x) + (((n div x) + (n mod x)) div (x - 1))
```

First comes from `(ab+c) mod d = ((a mod d) (b mod d) + (c mod d)) mod d`.

Second comes from expanding `n = ax + b = a(x-1) + a + b`, while dividing by `x-1`.